# Hacer que div o label actúe como checkbox

Tags: html, css, formularios, checkbox, entrada

Quiero que el label actue como un checkbox, he mirado este ejemplo pero a mi no me funciona... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523213/create-a-div-that-acts-like-an-html-checkbox

Tengo una estructura como esta:

```
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 centrar-div">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="checkbox">                                        
               <label class="label-cliente" for="clientes_type_muestraPrecio">
               <input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraPrecio" name="clientes_type[muestraPrecio]" value="1"> Muestra precio</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


.label-cliente {
        background: #5e5e5e;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked +.label-cliente{
        background: #2d89ef;

    }
```

Comment: Con esa misma estructura, no es posible, tendrías que emplear un script que cambie el orden de la estructura o que añada un span al label justo al lado del input, para que este se comporte como checkbox, pero no se si puedas o quieras, añadir a tu proyecto ese código javascript. Por cierto, esta estructura .checkbox `input[type=checkbox]:checked +.label-cliente`  no funcionará, porque sólo puedes (con css) simular "un evento de click" para aplicar estilos únicamente al hermano o hijo, pero no al padre, contenedor o ancestro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edito con solución JS (Jquery)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Seleccionamos todos los checkboxes y editamos su label más cercana     
  $("input:not(:checked)").closest("label").css("background-color", "#505050");
    $("input:checked").closest("label").css("background-color", "green");

     //Ten en cuenta que estamos seleccionando por clase label-cliente. Como estamos jugando con los children (en este caso los input) no deberías tener problemas si tienes varios label/input pero tenlo en cuenta.
      $(".label-cliente").click(function(){
        //Si el hijo está checked le ponemos a la label el color #2d89ef si no el #5e5e5e
        if($(this).children().is(":checked"))
        {
          $(this).css( "background-color", "green" );
        }
        else
        {
          $(this).css( "background-color", "#505050" );
        }  
      });
    });
```

```css
.label-cliente{
    background-color: #505050;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.checkbox-cliente[type=checkbox]{
   display:none;
}

.checkbox-cliente[type=checkbox]:checked + .checkbox-cliente{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formularioEditarCliente" action="/app_dev.php/gestion_usuarios_portal/43007414/clienteedit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 centrar-div">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraPrecio"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraPrecio" name="clientes_type[muestraPrecio]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1" checked="checked"> Muestra precio</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraDescuento"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraDescuento" name="clientes_type[muestraDescuento]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1" checked="checked"> Muestra descuento</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraStock"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraStock" name="clientes_type[muestraStock]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1" checked="checked"> Muestra stock</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraNotas"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraNotas" name="clientes_type[muestraNotas]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1" checked="checked"> Muestra notas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraVerde"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraVerde" name="clientes_type[muestraVerde]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1" checked="checked"> Muestra verde</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraPVPRecomendado"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraPVPRecomendado" name="clientes_type[muestraPVPRecomendado]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1" checked="checked"> Muestra p v p recomendado</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraPrecioNeto"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraPrecioNeto" name="clientes_type[muestraPrecioNeto]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Muestra precio neto</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_descubreDescuento"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_descubreDescuento" name="clientes_type[descubreDescuento]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Descubre descuento</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_comprarNegativo"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_comprarNegativo" name="clientes_type[comprarNegativo]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Comprar negativo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_limiteStock"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_limiteStock" name="clientes_type[limiteStock]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Limite stock</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_filtraMarcas"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_filtraMarcas" name="clientes_type[filtraMarcas]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Filtra marcas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaPedidos"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaPedidos" name="clientes_type[consultaPedidos]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta pedidos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaAlbaranes"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaAlbaranes" name="clientes_type[consultaAlbaranes]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta albaranes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraObservacionesArticulo"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraObservacionesArticulo" name="clientes_type[muestraObservacionesArticulo]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Muestra observaciones articulo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaAlbaranesPorFechas"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaAlbaranesPorFechas" name="clientes_type[consultaAlbaranesPorFechas]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta albaranes por fechas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaPedidosPorFechas"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaPedidosPorFechas" name="clientes_type[consultaPedidosPorFechas]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta pedidos por fechas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_anyadeArticulosAsociadosCesta"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_anyadeArticulosAsociadosCesta" name="clientes_type[anyadeArticulosAsociadosCesta]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Anyade articulos asociados cesta</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_muestraStockAlmacenes"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraStockAlmacenes" name="clientes_type[muestraStockAlmacenes]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Muestra stock almacenes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaNeumaticos"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaNeumaticos" name="clientes_type[consultaNeumaticos]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta neumaticos</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaArticulosPorMarca"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaArticulosPorMarca" name="clientes_type[consultaArticulosPorMarca]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta articulos por marca</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_consultaPedidosPendientes"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_consultaPedidosPendientes" name="clientes_type[consultaPedidosPendientes]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Consulta pedidos pendientes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_mostrarFondoPersonalizado"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_mostrarFondoPersonalizado" name="clientes_type[mostrarFondoPersonalizado]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Mostrar fondo personalizado</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_mostrarReferenciasInternas"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_mostrarReferenciasInternas" name="clientes_type[mostrarReferenciasInternas]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Mostrar referencias internas</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_mostrarSoloVerdesCuandoHayStock"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_mostrarSoloVerdesCuandoHayStock" name="clientes_type[mostrarSoloVerdesCuandoHayStock]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Mostrar solo verdes cuando hay stock</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_ordenargruposMontajePorArticulo"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_ordenargruposMontajePorArticulo" name="clientes_type[ordenargruposMontajePorArticulo]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Ordenargrupos montaje por articulo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_desglosaStockAlmacenMasTotal"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_desglosaStockAlmacenMasTotal" name="clientes_type[desglosaStockAlmacenMasTotal]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Desglosa stock almacen mas total</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_mostrarNetoConPvpDto"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_mostrarNetoConPvpDto" name="clientes_type[mostrarNetoConPvpDto]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Mostrar neto con pvp dto</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label class="label-cliente col-md-3" for="clientes_type_accesosTecdoc"><input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_accesosTecdoc" name="clientes_type[accesosTecdoc]" class="checkbox-cliente" value="1"> Accesos tecdoc</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmBYQQ)

**Respuesta original:**

Tienes mal formado el `html`. El `input` no está bien cerrado (lo estás cerrando con un `</label>`)

Además, no estás ocultando el checkbox (entiendo que quieres hacerlo).

```css
.label-cliente {
        background: #5e5e5e;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .checkbox input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}
    .checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked +.label-cliente{
        background: #2d89ef;

    }
```

```html
 <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 centrar-div">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="checkbox">         
            <input type="checkbox" id="clientes_type_muestraPrecio" name="clientes_type[muestraPrecio]" value="1"/>
               <label class="label-cliente" for="clientes_type_muestraPrecio">Muestra precio</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No está funcionando de esta manera... Para empezar, los inputs están creados con symfony forms y tienen esta estructura en el inspector: a ver si te sirve... https://i.gyazo.com/298299d122b44af0e8e4416be609c70f.png

Comment: Le he quitado los divc con col-md-2 para que no tenga tanto lio

Comment: En esta pregunta de SO hablan de un caso como el tuyo y a tenor de las respuestas me parece que no es posible hacerlo puramente con CSS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316966/css-checkboxes-radio-buttons-when-input-is-inside-label

Comment: Y no se puede hacer algo del estilo de coger todos los input de tipo checkbox de una plantilla `input[type=checkbox]:checked { background: blue}`por ejemplo?

Comment: Cierto, podrías hacer algo así. Aunque más que por tipo filtraría por clase o por id para no afectar a otros elementos.

Comment: Podrías ponerme un ejemplo de eso que he dicho, porque lo estoy intentando y no me funciona... O abrir un chat privado(no sé como se hace) para no tener que poner aquí tal cantidad de cosas, gracias

Comment: Perdona, se me ha ido la olla y me he liado. Con lo que has puesto no vas a lograr cambiar el fondo del label. Me temo que tendrás que recurrir javascript.

Comment: Y cómo puedo hacer que al cargar esa información los que ya estén `checked` sean de un color y los que no de otro, y luego que al cambiarlos también cambien de color?

Comment: Mira esto es lo que tengo : https://codepen.io/Brokhael/pen/PRBZmY

Comment: Edito mi respuesta con una solución JS (jQuery)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente!!